# Chinese to English Translation Painting

Tags: translation

[image]

Hello, would somebody be able to translate this image for me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The word is:

> 国色天香
> 甲子首春，仿新罗山人，尽意乡阳
> 写于湖山之滨

> 国色天香

国色天香 is a Chinese idiom (成语) which means 'national beauty and heavenly fragrance' from the word. It is another name of peony (牡丹), and it is usually used to describe a pretty woman.

> 甲子首春

甲子 is the first of the sexagenary cycle (干支). It is often used to mark the years. 首春 means the very first spring.

> 仿新罗山人

仿 means 'to imitate'. 新罗山人 is a famous artist named 华嵒(1682－1756) in Qing Dynasty (清朝). 新罗山人 is his alias (号). He is well-known as an outstanding artist in 扬州八怪.

> 尽意乡阳

尽意 means 'to fully express one's feelings, to relax, etc.' 乡阳 might be a place which I am not familiar with.

> 写于湖山之滨

写 means 'to write'. 于 means 'at'. 湖山之滨 means 'the coast of Hushan'. This sentense tells the place where the artist created the artwork.

> I'm not good at English. So please correct my mistakes.